# I have table rows selected with up and down arrows but want to be able to click them too

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have table rows selected with up and down arrows working but want to be able to click them too. When I click on a row nothing then shows as selected currently. I also want to be able to use the content of the first cell of the last selected row as part of the URL in the buttons underneath.
Can anyone help?
Here is the code I have so far:
Javascript, css, html

```js
(
function() {
  var trows = document.getElementById("mstrTable").rows;
  var selectedRow = 1;

  for (var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t) {
    trow = trows[t];
    trow.className = t === 1 ? "highlighted" : "normal";
    trow.onclick = highlightRow;
  }//end for

  function highlightRow(rowObj, index) {
    rowObj = rowObj || this;
    index = index || selectedRow;
    trows[index].className = "normal";
    rowObj.className = "highlighted";
    selectedRow = rowObj.rowIndex;
  }//end function

  function kbNavigate(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var key = evt.keyCode;
    switch (key) {
      case 38: // UP arrow
        if(selectedRow === 1) return;
        highlightRow(trows[selectedRow-1], selectedRow);
        break;
      case 40: // DOWN arrow
        if(selectedRow === trows.length-1) return;
        highlightRow(trows[selectedRow+1], selectedRow);
        break;
    }
  }

  document.onkeydown = kbNavigate;
}//end function
)();//end script
```

```css
body {background: #000042;}

.cas {
        font-size: 20pt;
        /*font-family: fixedsys, LucidaTerminal, monospace;*/
        font-family: Courier, monospace;
        color: Gold;
}

cas_h1 {
        font-size: 30pt;
}

table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
        border: 2px solid Gold;
        color: Gold;
        padding: 8px;

}

td, th {
        font-size: 20pt;
        /*font-family: fixedsys, LucidaTerminal, monospace;*/
        font-family: Courier, monospace;
}

.cont {
        border: none;
}

tr.normal td {
        color: Gold;
        background-color: #000042;
}
tr.highlighted td {
        color: black;
        background-color: OliveDrab;
        font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>cas</title>
<link href="cas.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<p class='cas'>
<br>
<cas_h1>CAS</cas_h1><br>
<br>
<table class='cont'>
<tr>
<td class='cont'>

<table id="mstrTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Order</td>
<td>Customer</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td>1234567</td>
<td>Smith</td>
</tr>
<td>1234566</td>
<td>Smith</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='cont'>
<button type='button' style='height: 30px;width: 80px' onclick='window.location.href="action1.php?order=1234567"'>Action 1</button>
<button type='button' style='height: 30px;width: 80px' onclick='window.location.href="action2.php?order=1234567"'>Action 2</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</p>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cas_table.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JavaScript` passes an event object as the first argument to click handlers. This makes the first argument to `highlightRow` an event object instead of a falsy value so that you could default it to `this`.

the code below fixes that problem by simply wrapping the click handler like so

```
trow.onclick = function(e){ highlightRow(this); };
```

```js
(
function() {
 
  var trows = document.getElementById("mstrTable").rows;
  var selectedRow = 1;

  for (var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t) {
    trow = trows[t];
    trow.className = t === 1 ? "highlighted" : "normal";
    // wrap the click handler to achieve the desired behavior.
    trow.onclick = function(e){highlightRow(this)}; 
  }//end for
  
  // add action handlers
  document.querySelector('.action.action1').addEventListener('click', navigate('action1'));
  document.querySelector('.action.action2').addEventListener('click', navigate('action2'));
        
  function navigate(action){
    return function(){
      var row = trows[selectedRow];
      // querySelector gets the first matching item
      // so the following code will get the contents of the 
      // first cell of the selected row.
      var order = row.querySelector('td').innerHTML;
      var url = action + '.php?order=' + order;
      alert(url);
      // window.location.href = url;
     }
  }
    
  function highlightRow(rowObj, index) {
    rowObj = rowObj || this;
    index = index || selectedRow;
    trows[index].className = "normal";
    rowObj.className = "highlighted";
    selectedRow = rowObj.rowIndex;
  }//end function

  function kbNavigate(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var key = evt.keyCode;
    switch (key) {
      case 38: // UP arrow
        if(selectedRow === 1) return;
        highlightRow(trows[selectedRow-1], selectedRow);
        break;
      case 40: // DOWN arrow
        if(selectedRow === trows.length-1) return;
        highlightRow(trows[selectedRow+1], selectedRow);
        break;
    }
  }

  document.onkeydown = kbNavigate;
}//end function
)();//end script
```

```css
body {background: #000042;}

.cas {
        font-size: 20pt;
        /*font-family: fixedsys, LucidaTerminal, monospace;*/
        font-family: Courier, monospace;
        color: Gold;
}

cas_h1 {
        font-size: 30pt;
}

table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
        border: 2px solid Gold;
        color: Gold;
        padding: 8px;

}

td, th {
        font-size: 20pt;
        /*font-family: fixedsys, LucidaTerminal, monospace;*/
        font-family: Courier, monospace;
}

.cont {
        border: none;
}

tr.normal td {
        color: Gold;
        background-color: #000042;
}
tr.highlighted td {
        color: black;
        background-color: OliveDrab;
        font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>cas</title>
<link href="cas.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<p class='cas'>
<br>
<cas_h1>CAS</cas_h1><br>
<br>
<table class='cont'>
<tr>
<td class='cont'>

<table id="mstrTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Order</td>
<td>Customer</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td>1234567</td>
<td>Smith</td>
</tr>
<td>1234566</td>
<td>Smith</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='cont'>
<button type='button' style='height: 30px;width: 80px'  class="action action1">Action 1</button>
<button type='button' class="action action2" style='height: 30px;width: 80px'>Action 2</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</p>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cas_table.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** The actions have been updated to pull from the selected table row.

Comment: This worked great for the click problem. I just need to be able to get the content of the first cell of the last row selected to include in the url of the buttons beneath (currently hard coded).

Comment: You're a star. I actually got the url bit working myself and was going to post the updated code but I see you've beaten me to it. Many thanks :-)

Comment: I'm glad you got it working yourself. That is usually far more useful. Glad to help.